# Getting a variable from a PDO function array to another page

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, pdo

I have multiple rows in a table called `optionals` and I am trying to get them one by one in a single function.
Table contains:

```
id |   name   | stock
1  | article1 |  500
2  | article2 |  255
```

In **`functions.php`**

```
function getStocks($mysqli)
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM optionals");
    $result = $stmt->fetch_all();

    //get the first row values
    $nameOptional1 = $result[0][1]; 
    $stockOptional1 = $result[0][2];

    //get the second row values
    $nameOptional2 = $result[1][1]; 
    $stockOptional2 = $result[1][2];

   ... //and code continues until I reached the last row
}
```

A `var_dump($result[0])` will display:

```
C:\wamp64\www\functions.php:42:
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'article1' (length=19)
  2 => string '500' (length=3)
```

**1.** I want in **`index.php`** to show `$nameOptional1,` for example, but I can`t manage to do that. I tried something like:

`include_once "functions.php";`

`$nameOptional1 = getStocks($mysqli);`

`echo $nameOptional1;`

**2.** Is this a good approach to get every row values using prepared statements? If not, what can be the best approach? I just switched to PHP prepared statements due to impossibility of Sql injections.

Comment: Did you echo those variables in the function or return'ing it? Is the MySQL Native Driver installed for you to use [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)? Are you checking for errors via php's error reporting and on the query? If there is no user input, you don't need to use a prepared statement.

Comment: Yes, there is user input.

Comment: Seeing what you posted for code, this doesn't seem to be the case. But yeah, use them if user input is involved. Btw; you answered one question of a few more.

Comment: If i use `return $nameOptional1` and  `return $stockOptional1`
in index.php whatever `$stockOptional1 = getStocks($mysqli); $nameOptional1 = getStocks($mysqli);` will echo only the first return from function.

Comment: That's because returns only returns "one" argument unless you concatenate like this: `return $parameter1 . " " . $parameter2;` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php - You also need some form of loop; whether a `foreach` or a `while`.

Comment: Using return in function and echo any variable in index.php, will return me only the first return from that function.

Comment: It works MySQL Native Driver since it does echo the first return variable function.

Comment: And also var_dump on $result shows a multi dimensional array.

Comment: I am using Wamp with PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4

Comment: Concatenating return not sure if will help me a lot.

In index.php I will probably have a table and in one <td> will show article1 and in second <td> will show 500 from row1.

Comment: I think I will search for some sort of loop as you told me @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0):

```
   function getStocks($mysqli)
{
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM optionals");
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    // Fetch all
    mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //get the first row values
    $nameOptional1 = $result[0][1]; 
    $stockOptional1 = $result[0][2];

    //get the second row values
    $nameOptional2 = $result[1][1]; 
    $stockOptional2 = $result[1][2];

   ... //and code continues until I reached the last row
}
```